# MS Word: How to apply a template to a batch of docs and then change the template file change them all

Tags: microsoft-word

The title should say it all. The scenario:

- I created a template
- I made a bunch of docxs from the template
- I change the template dotx file.
- The bunch files get changed by above action.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no. The feature you're looking for is common in desktop publishing packages, but MS Word is far from being a member of that class.

All you can do is open them one at a time and use Attach Template with the Automatically Update Styles option selected. But even then, you're going to need to go in and manually adjust things. If you've changed a multi-level list the chances are near certain that the changes won't be included after the template change.